# how change the module that python uses?

Tags: python, numpy, module

I'm installing caffe2 in a remote server, and I used pip to install a module called Numpy.

The python(2.7.6) is in :

```
/usr/bin/python
```

The pip is in :

```
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

when I use 'pip show numpy':

```
Name: numpy
Version: 1.13.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

but when I try to import it in python:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> n.__version__
'1.8.2'
>>>>>> n.get_include()
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include'
```

so I tried export PYTHONPATH in relative rc files:

```
export PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages":$PYTHONPATH
```

but this doesn't help.

What's the next step should I take?

Comment: `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: As suggested by @AlexHall, `/usr/local/lib` probably comes before `/usr/lib` in your path. You can manipulate your path to change this order before importing numpy.

Comment: @P.Camilleri I don't have '/usr/lib' in my PYTHONPATH in my rc file. how should I change the order? and i actually see /usr/lib is in front of /usr/local/lib in 'sys.path'.

Answer (score 3):

The way to avoid all this confusion is to always use a virtualenv, and install the correct version of numpy there.

Comment: Or a system such as docker.

Comment: in fact, I didn't mean to use python, but I need to make and build caffe2. In the makefiles, it uses some relative packages.